# why count prop does not update in Student

Tags: reactjs

why "count" prop does not update in Student?thank you.I couldn't find answer how to fix it.I am a novice to reactjs

**Student.js**

```
export const Student = (props) => {

        const { count } = props
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log(count)
            return () => {
                console.log(count)
            }
        })

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{count}</h1>
            </div>

        )

    }
```

**index.js**

```
const handleClick = (e)=>{
      console.log(count)
      count++
    }
    let count = 0
     ReactDOM.render(
        <React.Fragment>         
            <Student count={count} />
            <button onClick={handleClick}>count add</button>

         </React.Fragment>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I'm not even sure what's happening here; this is a pretty unusual structure for anything React.

Answer (score 2):

your count value is not reactive. You need to make it state variable

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

function App () {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const handleClick = ()=> {
      setCount(v => v + 1);
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>         
      <Student count={count} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>count add</button>
    </React.Fragment>
   );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I know you are right to do this, but I want to know why mine is wrong

Comment: read first line of my answer. simple variable update does not trigger re-render of components

Comment: I didn't see in the document that the props had to be updated with the usestate mode

Answer (score 0):

This is now how you update data in react
You must first declare a state and update the state.
This is how to create the state:
`const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)`
and onClick must look something like this

```
const handleClick = (e)=>{
      console.log(count)
      setCount(count+1)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

count must be in a state otherwise it will be ignored by React. Use something like this:

```
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
```

Then to update count, call setCount(x);

Answer (score 0):

Use useState() to save the count otherwise on re-rendering value of count will be lost.